# ASP.net: How can I run a Reflection.Type, and output the results into a webform textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've only been coding for a little over a year, so if I seem to be missing something obvious, feel free to explain.

I'm heading up a study group for my C# class, and want to put together an ASP.net page that can be run locally with VS and a browser, and where the user can build classes in the namespace, code a main method in a webform textbox, and see the output on the right side of the screen (like a web tutorial, except that security isn't a concern: I'm just going to throw a project up on Bitbucket).

So, I'm building, compiling, and instantiating a class and Main method, and have figured out how to access the DLL file created by the CompiilerResults, but I can't figure out how to execute the file from the code behind, or get any output into a string variable. I would settle for an execution, and seeing the results in the Console; the important thing is that the entered code has to run. Here is what I have (most of the commented code is there to test output):

The MasterPage:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="stylesheets" runat="server">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="MasterPage.master.css" type="text/css" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="header" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="codeColumn" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="outputColumn" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="headerLabel" Font-Size="X-Large" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <!-- User enters code here: -->
        <asp:TextBox ID="codeTextArea" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns ="50" Rows ="30" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <!-- Results of code, or caught errors, should be output here: -->
        <asp:TextBox ID="outputTextArea" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="30" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <!-- Clicking the submit button should start the code behind to handle errors, and run clean code: -->
        <asp:Button ID="submitButton" Text="Run!" OnClick="submitButton_Click" runat="server" />
    </form>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="footer" runat="server">
            <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" runat="server">First Tutorial</asp:HyperLink>
            <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" runat="server">Next Tutorial</asp:HyperLink>
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;

public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (codeTextArea.Text != null)
        {
            // Build a class and assembly:
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            string codeString = @"using System;namespace StudyGroup { public class WebProgram { 

            private String _outputString = ""output""; public static void Main() { ";
            codeString += codeTextArea.Text;
            codeString += @" } } }";
            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, codeString);
            var path = results.PathToAssembly;

            // Output:

            string outputString = "";

            // Error handling:

            if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                outputString += "You haz errors:\n";
                foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
                {
                    outputString += error.ErrorText;
                    outputString += "\n";
                }
                //throw new InvalidOperationException(outputString);
                outputTextArea.Text = outputString;
            }
            else
            {

                // Instantiate an instance and invoke Main method:

                var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
                var program = assembly.GetType("StudyGroup.WebProgram");
                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(program);
                var main = program.GetMethod("Main");
                main.Invoke(instance, null);

                // Add properties and methods of Type to output:

                outputString += instance.GetType();
                var methods = program.GetMethods();
                foreach(MethodInfo m in methods)
                {
                    outputString += m.Name;
                }
                var properties = program.GetProperties();
                foreach(PropertyInfo p in properties)
                {
                    outputString += p.Name;
                    outputString += p.GetMethod;
                }
                /*foreach (String s in results.Output)
                {
                    outputString += s;
                    outputString += "\n";
                }*/
                //outputString += Console.Out;

                // Output:

                Console.WriteLine(outputString);
                Console.ReadLine();
                outputTextArea.Text = outputString;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten the program to run in the console without Reflection.Type, using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start, sending the path to the DLL (or EXE) file, retrieved by the CompilerResults. However, I can't get the Console output into a variable. I set Console.Out to a StreamWriter and then a TextWriter, but neither seemed to have any effect from within my code behind, and putting the code directly into the codeString var, and writing the Console output to file, threw an error (this file being used by another process). I can post updated code, if anybody is interested.

Answer (score 0):

And, I think I've got it!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;

public partial class MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (codeTextArea.Text != null)
        {

            // Build a class and assembly:
            CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
            CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
            parameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
            string codeString = @"using System; using System.IO; namespace StudyGroup { public class WebProgram {  private String _outputString = ""output""; public static void Main() {  ";
            codeString += codeTextArea.Text;
            codeString += @" } } }";
            CompilerResults results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, codeString);
            var path = results.PathToAssembly;

            // Output:

            string outputString = "";

            // Error handling:

            if (results.Errors.HasErrors)
            {
                outputString += "You haz errors:\n";
                foreach (CompilerError error in results.Errors)
                {
                    outputString += error.ErrorText;
                    outputString += "\n";
                }
                //throw new InvalidOperationException(outputString);
                outputTextArea.Text = outputString;
            }
            else
            {

                // Instantiate an instance and invoke Main method:

                //var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
                var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.FileName = path;

                process.Start();

                var moreOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                outputString += moreOutput;

                // Output:

                Console.WriteLine(outputString);
                Console.ReadLine();
                outputTextArea.Text = outputString;
            }
        }
    }
}
```